# How would i figure out the price difference efficiently with PHP?

Tags: php

I have this [page](http://posnation.com/shop_pos/step2/Bakery) and if you scroll to the second "Customize" in the middle of the page and you click you will see my print_r() for the products and the thing i am trying to do is figure out the difference in price between the selected and the other two products....all three products are in the array and if you look just below that you will see the radio buttons that i need....here is my php which looks awful...any suggestions

```
$current_price = $product[$selected_product]['product_price'];

$standard_price = $product["standard"]['product_price'] - $current_price;
$business_price = $product["business"]['product_price']  - $current_price;
$premium_price = $product["premium"]['product_price'] - $current_price;

if($standard_price == 0){
    $standard_price = "included";
}
if($standard_price > 0){
    $standard_price = "subtract " . $standard_price;
}else{
    $standard_price = "add " . $standard_price;
}

if($business_price == 0){
    $business_price = "included";
}
if($business_price > 0){
    $business_price = "subtract " . $business_price;
}else{
    $business_price = "add " . $business_price;
}

if($premium_price == 0){
    $premium_price = "included";
}
if($premium_price > 0){
    $premium_price = "subtract " . $premium_price;
}else{
    $premium_price = "add " . $premium_price;
}
```

Comment: Your title is wrong. Plase short your problem in it  - not your feelings:)

Comment: I see a tad bit of refactoring that could be done. But I also would like to note this probably isn't the best place to request a code-review.

Comment: what sort of suggestion do you want? do you think you code it too long etc? Please clarify

Comment: also i was looking for a way to improve it because it prints out wrong....so if its a negative number it will print subract -120

Comment: and i feel like this can be condensed because there is alot of repeating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starter, and with seeing the repeated code, I'd break your comparison out in to a function. Re-use code instead of copy-paste:

```
function price_delta($base,$compare){
  if ($base == $compare)
    return 'included';
  $delta = $compare - $base;
  return $delta > 0 ? sprintf("add $%01.2f", $delta) : sprintf("subtract $%01.2f", $delta * -1);
}
```

Then it's a matter of:

```
$standard_price = price_delta($current_price, $product["standard"]['product_price']);
$business_price = price_delta($current_price, $product["business"]['product_price']);
$premium_price  = price_delta($current_price, $product["premium"]['product_price']);
```

**[DEMO](http://www.ideone.com/nj4X7)**

Comment: Modified a bit to use an [sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) with `%01.2f` (make the currency neat)

Answer (score 1):

```
$alt_prices=array('standard','business','premium');
$current_price = $product[$selected_product]['product_price'];
foreach($alt_prices as $alt_price){
    $$alt_price=$product[$alt_price]['product_price']-$current_price;
    if($$alt_price==0){
        $$alt_price='Included';
    }else{
        $$alt_price=($$alt_price>0)?'subtract '.abs($$alt_price):'add '.abs($$alt_price);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear what's going on – I wouldn't say it's awful, and suspect that any tidying will actually make things harder to see what's happening.

If this had 500 different versions I'd fix it!

You could make an array with the 3 prices in, then do a foreach to produce the outcomes, but I probably wouldn't bother – it's not slow, and it's easy to understand.